# How do I build this EF relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I can do this in the database but I want to understand how to do this code-first.

I have this class:

```
public class Component
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Component Master { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }
}
```

A component can have many child components.
A component can also be a child component in many other components.

I want to create a table that relates Component's ID's together. What is the best way to represent this?

Comment: What do you mean by *creating table that relates ids together*? Why not use table with FK for parent component?

Comment: That wouldn't work because a component can have more than one parent (master). I meant a cross-reference table such as in Dismissle's answer.

Comment: So, maybe you need collection of masters? Otherwise which one you want to pick as master?

Comment: Yeah, I had only wanted one master when I loaded child components but now I see what I need to do to get EF to understand the data structure I want. Dismissle's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a self referencing entity like this that can only have a single parent:

```
public class Component
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Component Master { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }

    // reference to the parent guid (if any)
    public Guid? MasterID { get; set; }
}
```

To configure the entity relationship do this in OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Component>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Components)
        .WithOptional(c => c.Master)
        .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.MasterID);
}
```

Another option is to set up an xref / join table instead of having it as a column on the Components table, but in that case you have a many to many relationship so instead of a single Component master, you have a collection of Components as the Master. You can enforce it to only ever be a single parent using a unique key, but you still have to model it as a collection from EF's perspective.

Here is an example of using an Xref table:

```
public class Component
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Component> Masters { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }       
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Component>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Components)
        .WithMany(c => c.Masters)
        .Map(xref => xref.MapLeftKey("ParentID").MapRightKey("ChildID").ToTable("ComponentXref"));
}
```

Comment: This creates what I would expect to see in the database but nothing saves to it? Only the IDs are passed back from the UI, I am creating a new Component, setting its ID, adding the parent component to Masters and adding the child to the masters Child collection. Nothing appears in the database - is something missing?

Comment: @Cari I would have to see your code to understand what you mean.

Comment: Nevermind, I was assuming things would magically happen when I needed to write some more code.